# Need help php to json array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a string below

```
$string = ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45
```

I would like the JSON output be like

```
 [{"name":"website","data":["ot","om","we","ff"]}]
```

and

```
 [{"name":"websitedata","data":["4","6","34","45"]}]
```

what I've tried

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT month, wordpress, codeigniter, highcharts FROM project_requests");
$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'website';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'websitedata';

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['month'];
  }
$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

but the above code is applicable only if the data are present in rows from a mysql table, what i want is achieve the same result with the data from the above string. that is

```
  $string = ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45
```

**NEW UPDATE:**

I would like to modify the same string

```
$string = ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45
```

into

json output:

```
[
     {
          "type" : "pie",
          "name" : "website",
          "data" : [
               [
                    "ot",
                     4
               ],
               [  
                    "om",
                    6
               ],
               [  
                    "we",
                    34
               ]
           ]
     }
]
```

I have updated the answer please check the json part, I would like the php code.
regards

Comment: You should use some sort of regular expression or string manipulation to convert string to json

Comment: Please update your question with an extra section about the extra details for 'pie charts'. So that we know exactly what is required.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent added the edits please check now sir.

Comment: I tested my answer and it work now with the graph script. Could you please test it for yourself and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `explode()` on the `>`s, and then loop through the elements:

```
$string = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

$array1 = [
    'name'=>'website',
    'data'=>[]
]
$array2 = [
    'name'=>'websitedata',
    'data'=>[]
]
foreach(explode('>', $string) as $index => $value){
    if($index & 1) //index is odd
        $array2['data'][] = $value;
    else //index is even
        $array1['data'][] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($array1); //prints {"name":"website","data":["ot","om","we","ff"]}
echo json_encode($array2); //prints {"name":"websitedata","data":["4","6","34","45"]}
```

A solution using `preg_match_all()`:

```
$string = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

preg_match_all('/(\w+)>(\d+)/', $string, $matches);

$array1 = [
    'name'=>'website',
    'data'=> $matches[1]
];
$array2 = [
    'name'=>'websitedata',
    'data'=> $matches[2]
];

echo json_encode($array1); //prints {"name":"website","data":["ot","om","we","ff"]}
echo json_encode($array2); //prints {"name":"websitedata","data":["4","6","34","45"]}
```

### Update:

To get the second type of array you wanted, use this:

```
//since json_encode() wraps property names in double quotes (which prevents the chart script from working), you'll have to build the json object manually
$string = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

preg_match_all('/(\w+)>(\d+)/', $string, $matches);

$data = [];
foreach($matches[1] as $index => $value){
    if(isset($matches[2][$index]))
        $data[] = '["' . $value . '",' . $matches[2][$index] . ']';
}

$type = 'pie';
$name = 'website';

echo $jsonString = '[{type:"' . $type . '",name:"' . $name . '",data:[' . implode(',', $data) . ']}]'; // prints [{type:"pie",name:"website",data:[["ot",4],["om",6],["we",34],["ff",45]]}]
```

### Update #2:

This code uses `explode()`, and although it's probably not the most efficient way of doing it, it works.

```
//since json_encode() wraps property names in double quotes (which prevents the chart script from working), you'll have to build the json object manually
$string = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

$keys = [];
$values = [];

foreach(explode('>', $string) as $key => $value){
    if(!($key & 1)) //returns true if the key is even, false if odd
        $keys[] = $value;
    else
        $values[] = $value;
}

$data = [];
foreach($keys as $index => $value){
    if(isset($values[$index]))
        $data[] = '["' . $value . '",' . $values[$index] . ']';
}

$type = 'pie';
$name = 'website';

echo $jsonString = '[{type:"' . $type . '",name:"' . $name . '",data:[' . implode(',', $data) . ']}]'; // prints [{type:"pie",name:"website",data:[["ot",4],["om",6],["we",34],["ff",45]]}]
```

Comment: I thought that 'property names' (strings) in JSON were required to have double quotes (")? These are treated 'correctly' in 'javascript' whether you use them 'quoted' or not? [A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes - www.json.org...](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: @RyanVincent I thought so too, but the graphs script he uses the object for doesn't work (for me at least) when they *are* wrapped in double quotes

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. more investigation needed - It is not really that complex a 'standard' to follow... sigh... ;-/

Comment: @Jonan hello sir! sir, is it possible to give this same answer without using preg_match_all ? like simply using arrays

Comment: @vigneshs I updated my answer, it now makes use of `explode()`

Comment: @vigneshs that's probably because they don't have php 5.6 yet, try `array()` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 2):

This should work, though there are probably better ways to do it.

```
$string = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

$website = ["name" => "website", "data" => []];
$websiteData = ["name" => "websitedata", "data" => []];

foreach(explode(">", $string) as $i => $s) {
    if($i % 2 === 0) {
        $website["data"][] = $s;
    } else {
        $websiteData["data"][] = $s;
    }
}

echo json_encode($website);
echo json_encode($websiteData);
```

A regex alternative:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z]+)>(\d+)/", $string, $matches);

$website = ["name" => "website", "data" => $matches[1]];
$websiteData = ["name" => "websitedata", "data" => $matches[2]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
$string = 'ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45';
$string_split = explode('>', $string);

$data = array("name" => "website");
$data2 = $data;

foreach ($string_split as $key => $value)
{
    if (((int)$key % 2) === 0)
    {
        $data["data"][] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $data2["data"][] = $value;
    }
}

$json1 = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$json2 = json_encode($data2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

echo $json1;
echo $json2;
```

**Output:**

> {"name":"website","data":["ot","om","we","ff"]}
>
> {"name":"website","data":[4,6,34,45]}

Regards.

Comment: sir this one worked, is it possible to produce {name:'website',type:'pie',"data":[['ot',4],['om',6]['we',34],['ff',45]]} I need it in series format highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic see that link for implementing the json to be used for pie chart thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
$strings = explode('>', 'ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45');
// print_r($string);

$x = 0;
$string['name'] = 'website';
$numbers['name'] = 'websitedata';

foreach ($strings as $s)
{
    if ($x == 0) {
        $string['data'][] = $s;
        $x = 1;
    } else {
        $numbers['data'][] = $s;
        $x = 0;
    }
}


print_r(json_encode($string));
echo "<br/>";
print_r(json_encode($numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual - it is long winded but shows all the steps to get to the required output.

```
<?php //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822896/need-help-php-to-json-array

// only concerned about ease of understnding not code size or efficiency.

// will speed it up later...

$inString = "ot>4>om>6>we>34>ff>45";

$outLitRequired =  '[{"name":"website","data":["ot","om","we","ff"]}]';
$outValueRequired = '[{"name":"websitedata","data":["4","6","34","45"]}]';

// first: get a key / value array...
$itemList = explode('>', $inString);

/* debug */ var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, $itemList);

// outputs ------------------------------------
$outLit = array();
$outValue = array();

// ok we need to process them in pairs - i like iterators...
reset($itemList); // redundant but is explicit

// build both output 'data' lists
while (current($itemList)) {
    $outLit[] = current($itemList);
    next($itemList); // advance the iterator.

    $outValue[] = current($itemList);
    next($itemList);
}

/* debug */ var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, $itemList, $outLit, $outValue);

// make the arrays look like the output we want...
// we need to enclose them as arrays to get the exact formatting required

// i do that in the 'json_encode' statements.

$outLit = array('name' => 'website', 'data' => $outLit);
$outValue = array('name' => 'websitedata', 'data' => $outValue);

// convert to JSON.
$outLitJson = json_encode(array($outLit));
$outValueJson = json_encode(array($outValue));

// show  required and calculated values...

/* debug */ var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, 'OutLit', $outLitRequired, $outLitJson);
/* debug */ var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, 'OutValue', $outValueRequired, $outValueJson);
```